# Perform Delete, Edit and search operation on a file using php

Tags: php, file, file-handling

I have a task to do in which i have to list the directories with it's files which i did, but i don't understand how to delete file or edit specific file in the directories any help will be appreciated Thanks.

```
<?php
  error_reporting(0);

 if(isset($_GET['dir']))
{
 // /$path = 'E:\xampp\\'.$_GET['dir'];
 $path = $_GET['dir'];
}
 else
{
    $path = 'E:\xampp\\';
}

 if(is_dir($path))
 {
    $arrDir = scandir($path);
    echo "<ul>";

 foreach ($arrDir as $key => $value) 
 {

    echo "<a href='http://localhost/vishrut/FileUpload/filelist.php? 
    dir=".$path.'/'.$value."'>".$value.'</a><br>';   
 }

 echo "</ul>";

}
 else
{    
    echo "<textarea>";
    echo file_get_contents($path);
    echo "</textarea>"."<br>";     
}   

?>
```

Comment: did you see my answer?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of PHP's functions to handle files: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php

For your needs see these:

- [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to read the entire file contents
- [file_put_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) to write the content in a file
- [unlink](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) to delete a file

So, the steps to modify a file may be:

1. get the complete contents with `file_get_contents`:

   ```
   $contents = file_get_contents($filePath);
   ```
2. apply your edits to the `$contents` content:

   ```
   $newContents = ...
   ```
3. overwrite the file content:

   ```
   file_put_contents($filePath, $newContents);
   ```

To delete a file is simple:

```
unlink($filePath);
```

**It's important to note that your code is subjected to injection** because you don't check the user data passed with `$_GET`.

If your script will be used **only by you** it's ok, instead you must check all user input: the first rule of Web programming is **NEVER TRUST YOUR USERS**! Also trusted users may write wrong characters in the url and that may have unexpected results (e.g. delete the wrong file!)

Read https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.security.script_injection.php